# Media query not working while using hostname in URL

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am designing a responsive html page containing images and tables.
Please see below code block of html.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            body {
                /*font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, Serif;*/
                font-size: 11.0pt;
                font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif";
            }

            #page-wrap {
                margin: 5px;
            }

            p {
                margin: 20px 0;
            }

            /*
                        Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops
                        */
            table {
                width: 100%;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            /* Zebra striping */
            tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
                background: #eee;
            }

            th {
                background: #5388FF;
                color: white;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            td, th {
                padding: 6px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style>


        <style>
            @media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {

                img {
                    width: 100%;
                }

                /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
                table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
                    display: block;
                }

                    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
                    thead tr {
                        position: absolute;
                        top: -9999px;
                        left: -9999px;
                    }

                tr {
                    border: 1px solid #ccc;
                }

                td {
                    /* Behave  like a "row" */
                    border: none;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
                    position: relative;
                    padding-left: 50%;
                }

                    td:before {
                        /* Now like a table header */
                        position: absolute;
                        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
                        top: 6px;
                        left: 6px;
                        width: 45%;
                        padding-right: 10px;
                        white-space: nowrap;
                    }

                    /*
                Label the data
                */
                    td:nth-of-type(1):before {
                        content: "Employee ID";
                    }

                    td:nth-of-type(2):before {
                        content: "Employee Name";
                    }

                    td:nth-of-type(3):before {
                        content: "Employee Address";
                    }

                    td:nth-of-type(4):before {
                        content: "Employee Phone";
                    }
            }

            /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
            @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
                body {
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    width: 320px;
                }

                img {
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }

            /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
            @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
                body {
                    width: 495px;
                }

                img {
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>


        <div id="page-wrap">

            <img max-width="100%" src="Images/image001.png">

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Employee ID</th>
                        <th>Employee Name</th>
                        <th>Employee Address</th>
                        <th>Employee Phone</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>101</td>
                        <td>John Smith</td>
                        <td>US</td>
                        <td>45454545</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>102</td>
                        <td>Dave Furber</td>
                        <td>US</td>
                        <td>45454546</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

When I browse the html page using hostname like http://mymachine:6000/test.html, the media query does not work in IE11 but works in Chrome.

However when I browse the page using IP in the URL the media query works just fine and the page is rendered correctly in Chrome and IE 11 for all the devices.

Can someone provide me inputs on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Vinayak

Comment: Update: The page works fine if I do not host it in IIS site.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will affect it, but there's no need for you to be using two `<style>` blocks on the same page, try adding the styles into just one block

Comment: Hi Sam , Thanks for the input, I combined all the styles into one block. Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason IE was using IE7 mode for rendering this page.
Reference : [Link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb4ed130-c1ae-4579-bc7b-476d3f6dd0fb/media-query-not-working-while-using-hostname-in-url-for-ie11?forum=ieitprocurrentver) 
Adding the below tag solved the problem !!

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Thanks,

Vinayak

Answer (score 0):

Are You using some kind of testing environment like XAMPP? It would also be helpful if we could see Your Html (cant comment, don't have enough reputation).

Comment: I am not using any testing environment. I have hosted the page on my Windows 7 machine. Please see the full html code above.

Comment: I think You problem is with the environment, I can't exactly tell if the browser renders local and hosted files differently, but with IE this might be the problem. Personally when I develop something, I always use XAMPP or something similar to see the true result how the code would react in real life and without such local servers You wouldn't be able to correctly display PHP, Javascript, etc.

Comment: Update: The page works fine if I do not host it in IIS site.